# Cannon.js 2 plane overlay collision

Tags: collision, cannon.js

i have a `THREE.PlaneGeometry` named `floor` set on bottom and other `THREE.PlaneGeometry` named `grass` set slightly `0.2` on top of the `floor`.

when my raycastvehicle wheel drive over on both of the plane, the collision randomly detect `floor` and `grass` which majority detect `floor` but not `grass`.
How can I make the collision merely detect `grass` but not `floor` cause `grass` should be the priority since its on top of the `floor`?

Comment: updated : i fixed it to detect the world contact manually in each tick .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this is to use *collision groups and masks* for your planes and vehicle rays. This way you could choose which objects should be hit by rays and which ones that should be ignored.

However, the [CANNON.RaycastVehicle class](https://github.com/schteppe/cannon.js/blob/6e0d352e1bcf97746db47da7302cf08a8ad89f54/src/objects/RaycastVehicle.js) does not yet support collision groups/masks. For a quick fix, you could patch Cannon, or perhaps monkey-patch `RaycastVehicle.prototype.castRay`.

In any case, please submit a [feature request](https://github.com/schteppe/cannon.js/issues) for collision group/mask support in RaycastVehicle.